# Xna Texture.GetColor not getting right color information

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have a class called `BaseDrawableComponent` that inherits from `DrawableGameComponent`

For other hand I have a class that inherits from this `BaseDrawableComponent` called `MySceneObject` with a Draw method with the following code:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Color[] pixelColours = new Color[this.Texture.Width * this.Texture.Height];
    this.Texture.GetData<Color>(pixelColours);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

When I debug, I'm putting a breakpoint on `base.Draw(gametime)`. I checked the array `pixelColours` and the value every item is `R:255 G:255 B:255 A:255`. The image has a lot of different colors, so I don't know why all the item array values is always the same.

Comment: When you draw the texture what does it look like? I doubt the GetData is returning wrong results.

Comment: When i draw it, the texture is well rendered so i cannot imagine whats happening.